# Will I be disappointed with these brakes?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a cyclocross bike, it came with Tektro Lyra brakes - they were useless so I fitted a flat bar so I could use my spare hydraulic MTB brakes.

I'm just about to buy some new brakes to replace the Lyra's and allow my bike to use the drop bars again.

Out of these what would you get?

- TRP HY/RD
- TRP Spyre
- Shimano RS505

I keep thinking that I will be disappointed with the Spyres even though I can see them fitted on some fairly decent Giant bikes. If I shell out for the HY/RDs I keep thinking might as well pay the extra for the RS505s, but then I might need to get some more tape for my bars and some other costs that I haven't thought of. (I could buy an old banger car for the price of those brake levers!)

What would you do?

Comment: Voting to close: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: A lot of people have been quite happy with mechanical disc brakes on cross/road bikes for years. The Lyra's not well designed brakes to begin with, so I wouldn't use them as justification to write off mechanical discs. But the right choice depends on what you like, where you ride and what you can afford. And SE isn't good for that format.

Comment: Will you be disappointed? I've no idea -- it depends on your expectations and demeanour. What would I do? This isn't a site for posting polls, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have TRP Spyre on my Jamis Renegate Expat 2016. My friends also have them on other bikes. We like these brakes. They work good and smooth.
I had several situations on the road when I was forced to stop immediately, and these brakes worked great.

They a mechanical, it means that they are simple and robust. You can easily do service at home and repair them if you are in travel. I value it because I like bicycle tourism :)
Their pads squeezing the disk from two sides.

The only disadvantage for me is their price in general and price for brake pads for them (maybe this problem actual only for Russia). But you can use cheaper pads from Shimano and other analogues.

I hope this helps.